# Hilt Worker not getting initiated. Works fine when I use only default params for worker constructor, when I add third param it fails

Tags: android, kotlin, worker, dagger-hilt

Seems Like for some reason its not using my custom worker, Instead initiates default Worker.. Following is the code snippet

```
@HiltWorker
class RequestsWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
@Assisted appContext: Context,
@Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
var dbRepository: DBRepository) : Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
//doWorK...
}
```

Application.class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class Application: Application(), Configuration.Provider {

@Inject
lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
}

override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
    return  Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
        .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
        .build()
}
}
```

Start worker from fragment

```
private fun initWorker() {
    val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<RequestsWorker>().build()
    WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueue(request)
}
```

I get following error

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sala.cbc.backgroundsync.RequestsWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2321)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2167)
    at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:244)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:136)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

In manifest I added following in application tag

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove">
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your **hilt-android-gradle-plugin** version inside your **Project level build.gradle** file.

It worked for me by upgrading the version from **2.37 to 2.38.1**.

Now it should look like this,

> classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"